# Ramda sum with object dinamic

Tags: javascript, node.js, reduce, ramda.js

I need to generate several objects related by custodianCenter and in turn perform the sum of the value attribute. I managed to perform a groupby for its attribute but I can't generate an attribute that adds all the values ​​in relation to that attribute:

```
const data = [
  {
    "_id": "+UJIRvYOSXysumiDdQTfkA==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "custodianCenter": "Pastagens",
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": "Fazenda",
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234,
    "property": "Fertilizantes"
  },
  {
    "_id": "XghoVK9uRke90xnsPZVjYw==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "comment": "Comentário 1",
    "custodianCenter": "Pastagens",
    "custodianCenterValue": 22,
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": null,
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234,
    "property": "Gratificações"
  },
  {
    "_id": "mK+YXWeiTpGa3alAOENbvg==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "comment": "Comentário 1",
    "custodianCenter": "Pastagens",
    "custodianCenterValue": 22,
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": null,
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "property": null,
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234
  },
  {
    "_id": "g7fVa41uRey+K+8OnKBO9g==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "comment": "Comentário 1",
    "custodianCenter": "Pastagens",
    "custodianCenterValue": 22,
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": null,
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "property": null,
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234
  },
  {
    "_id": "GTZbvPnVQZ+7V4dfUjIT/w==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "category": "Gratificações",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "comment": "Comentário 1",
    "custodianCenter": "Mão de Obra",
    "custodianCenterValue": 22,
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": null,
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234
  }
]

const res = R.compose(
  R.groupBy(R.prop("custodianCenter"))
)(data)

console.log(res)
```

Being custodianCenter the cost center that is informed as the name of the array, the total attribute would be the sum of the value attribute and the quantity attribute would be the number of elements that the array has.

I need it to return something similar:

```
[
  {
    custodianCenter: 'Pastagem',
    total: 1240,
    quantity: 4
  },
  {
    custodianCenter: 'Mão de Obra',
    total: 234,
    quantity: 1
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  How has it failed?

Comment: To carry out the grouping by customerCenter I did the following:

const res = R.compose(
  R.groupBy(R.prop("custodianCenter"))
)(data)

Comment: It looks like you're new to StackOverflow.  Please read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).  We expect a reasonable amount of effort demonstrated in the question.  Please [edit] to show what you've tried and where it's failing.  People will likely be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "_id": "+UJIRvYOSXysumiDdQTfkA==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "custodianCenter": "Pastagens",
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": "Fazenda",
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234,
    "property": "Fertilizantes"
  },
  {
    "_id": "XghoVK9uRke90xnsPZVjYw==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "comment": "Comentário 1",
    "custodianCenter": "Pastagens",
    "custodianCenterValue": 22,
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": null,
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234,
    "property": "Gratificações"
  },
  {
    "_id": "mK+YXWeiTpGa3alAOENbvg==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "comment": "Comentário 1",
    "custodianCenter": "Pastagens",
    "custodianCenterValue": 22,
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": null,
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "property": null,
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234
  },
  {
    "_id": "g7fVa41uRey+K+8OnKBO9g==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "comment": "Comentário 1",
    "custodianCenter": "Pastagens",
    "custodianCenterValue": 22,
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": null,
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "property": null,
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234
  },
  {
    "_id": "GTZbvPnVQZ+7V4dfUjIT/w==",
    "arrival_date": "2022-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "attached_invoice": "invoice",
    "attachment_photo_receipt": "photo receipt",
    "category": "Gratificações",
    "code": "2432341-A",
    "comment": "Comentário 1",
    "custodianCenter": "Mão de Obra",
    "custodianCenterValue": 22,
    "date_received": "2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z",
    "description": "Description Financial Input 1",
    "expense_origin": 2,
    "installment_entry": true,
    "installment_payment": null,
    "invoice_number": 123,
    "nivel": null,
    "nivelData": [
      "71b292ed-8441-4d1e-a19f-b39fdad55d9a"
    ],
    "status": "input",
    "status_payment": null,
    "value": 234
  }
]

const { groupBy, pipe, values, map, sum, prop } = R;

const groupByCustodianCenter = R.groupBy(R.prop('custodianCenter'))
const sumValue = R.pipe(R.map(R.prop('value')), R.sum)
const addTotals = R.map(x => ({
  custodianCenter: x[0].custodianCenter,
  total: sumValue(x),
  quantity: x.length
}))
const result = R.pipe(groupByCustodianCenter, values, addTotals)

console.log(result(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```